# How to detect whether a class is used polymorphically?

Tags: c++

Suppose in one old project (>1M lines), there is a class named `Base` which has two virtual functions `foo` and `bar`

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo();
    virtual void bar();
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo();
    virtual void bar();
};
```

I suspect that `Base` is not used polymorphically, so `foo`/`bar` should not be virtual.

To confirm my ideas, I need to find out whether there is a statement like:

```
Base *b = new Derived;
```

but if we pass the pointer among a function, it would be hard to find out, for example:

```
Base *f()
{
  ...
  Derived *d = /* ... */;
  ...
  return d;
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It's unlikely that you will find a way to do this with 100% accuracy.

Comment: First idea that comes to mind is making `Base` a private base (which prevents conversion from `Derived *` to `Base *` without a C-style cast) and see if the code compiles.

Comment: You can also make `Base::foo` a pure virtual function and let the compiler detect whether the function is used polymorphically or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `Derived` inherit privately from `Base`. This will prevent implicit upcasts making `Base* b = new Derived;` a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two classes like following:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void a(){};
};

class Derived : public Base 
{
    virtual void b(){};
};
```

when you write code:
    Base* ptr = new Derived();
you could see ptr in watch window

```
ptr->__vfptr    0x00eb5740 const Derived::`vftable' *
[0] 0x00eb1028 Base::a(void)    *
```

You can look at the entire vtable if you add this helper variable:

```
void (**vt)() = *(void (***)())ptr;
```

and in watch window you could see:

```
vt,2    0x00eb5740 const Derived::`vftable' void (void)* *
[0] 0x00eb1028 Base::a(void)    void (void)*
[1] 0x00eb10aa Derived::b(void) void (void)*
```

so ,you could take a try.

Comment: OP is looking a way to find code like `Base* ptr = new Derived()`, but your answer need to find it first them check vtable???